# Are there any foreseeable problems with this function?

Tags: php, time, strtotime

I am using this function in one of my programs, and I am wondering if I could expect any complications with this function? For example, will this work at the end of December, the beginning of the new year?

```
$firstDayNextMonth = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('first day of next month'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using system time with this function. The users of your web application will be from different locations and from different time zones. Because of that, this may lead to wrong output for the users who are not in the same time zone of the server. To get the time zone you have to make use of client side programming (javascripts).

According to the manual [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) `strtotime('first day of next month')` function is preferred to get the first day of next month. There are no problems with getting the first day of January like you suspected..

Answer (score 0):

The function strtotime accepts many formats of date, like is described here:
http://www.gnu.org/software/shishi/manual/html_node/Date-input-formats.html

You just will have problems if the date format is none of this wich is described the documentation.

Also you should thinks about timezone. If the user was in a different timezone of the server, you will show the wrong datetime, so always use timestamp with timezone and localize this timestamp to show the right datetime using the i20n stardards.